# Containing shapes within a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a UserControl. Within this control I wish to draw ellipses. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to stop the ellipses from drawing outside of the UserControl. I was hoping by adding the ellipses to a grid, which is within a viewbox, that they wouldn't draw outside it.

Below you will find a link to a screenshot, The light grey rectangle is the custom control. I don't want the rings to appear outside. Can I crop the top and bottom somehow?

[image: ScreenShot of UserControl]

The lines are added as children of 'GridlinesGrid'.

[image: ScreenShot of Objects Panel]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Scott

Comment: If you post some xaml reproducing the issue you're more likely to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ClipToBounds` property.

Here's the documentation for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx

Comment: This was exactly what was needed! Thank you very much. It seems so obvious - Shame on me for not noticing it =]